# HTML javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html with javascript, but I don't know why it's not working. It's right now supposed to calculate the values of the two textboxes when the button is pressed. However nothing is happening.
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>HTML Räpellys 2</h1>
    <select id="mathType">
        <option value="0">Addition</option>
        <option value="1">Subtraction</option>
        <option value="2">Multiplication</option>
        <option value="3">Division</option>
        <option value="4">Shift Left</option>
        <option value="5">Shift Right</option>
        <option value="6">Increment</option>
        <option value="7">Decrement</option>
        <option value="8">AND</option>
        <option value="9">OR</option>
        <option value="A">XOR</option>
    </select>
    <p></p>
    <form>
        Value 1: <input type="text" id="val1" value=""></input>
        <p></p>
        Value 2: <input type="text" id="val2" value=""></input>
    </form>
    <p></p>
    <button onclick="mathFunc">Calculate!</button>
    <p></p>
    <script>
        function mathFunc() {
            var box1 = document.getElementById("val1").value;
            var box2 = document.getElementById("val2").value;

            if (document.getElementById("mathType").value == 0) {
                document.write(box1 + box2);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <noscript>Java is required to display this element!</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: edit the `<button onclick="mathFunc">Calculate!</button>`to `<button onclick="mathFunc()">Calculate!</button>`

Comment: If the code does not display correctly when posting here, please work on making it display correctly.

Comment: You also have to parse your values to Integers otherwise your trying to add strings which means 5+2=52. So the following `var box1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("val1").value);` will nean that 5+3=7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the function should be called on click: `onclick="mathFunc()"`.

Generally, I would recommend you not to use `document.write` in the code but for debugging purposes use browser console and `console.log` function.

**MDN:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript#Console.log_in_Browser_Console

Comment: I got the output value now, but javascript has some weird logic -> 1 + 2 = 12. Shouldn't that be 3?

Comment: @Baka94 Yes, it should be. `value` property returns string value, and `+` will do string concatenation. In order to fix that put `+` before the value or use `parseFloat` function: `parseFloat(box1) + parseFloat(box2)`.

Answer (score 0):

the `<form>` tag should contain the form elements...

eg 
`<form>
  <select...`

then I'd also make sure I don't get the string value of the input fields byt wrapping them with parseFloat(). eg:

`var box1 = parseFloat( document.getElementById("val1").value ) ;`

you also need to call the function as a function, basically what VisioN said above:
`onclick="mathFunc()"`